# UITapGesture not working even with isUserInteraction enabled set to true

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Ok here is my situation:

- Chat app that has a custom `inputAccessoryView` (Overrode of course)
- Need to implement reply to chat functionality (Just like whatsapp where user can reply to individual chats)
- I'm showing new view, `keyBoardReplyView`, which is a short snippet of the chat that I am reply to on top of the `inputAccessoryView`(Adding this programatically using auto-layout)
- This new view `keyBoardReplyView` contains an image view with a close icon
- When i tap on this close icon, I want to remove the `KeyboardReplyView` but unfortunately, the tap gesture does not seem to fire

**Note:**
I have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to true

**What I have tried:**
I read in a stack post that I must set the parent view user interaction to true and I tried that as well but still does not work

**Code of how I am adding my KeyboardReplyView on top of inputAccessoryView:**

```
let keyboardReplyView = KeyboardSupplementaryReplyView()
    
    fileprivate func setupReplyViewForKeyboard(withTitleColor: UIColor){
        keyboardReplyView.titleLabel.textColor = withTitleColor
        keyboardReplyView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleReplyMessageClose))
        keyboardReplyView.closeImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        inputAccessoryView?.addSubview(keyboardReplyView)
        keyboardReplyView.anchor(top: nil, leading: inputAccessoryView?.leadingAnchor, bottom: inputAccessoryView?.topAnchor, trailing: inputAccessoryView?.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 0, height: 60))
    }
```

**Here is the code to the view:**

```
class KeyboardSupplementaryReplyView: UIView {
    let closeImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        let boldConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .bold)
        let boldBell = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle", withConfiguration: boldConfig)
        iv.image = boldBell
        return iv
    }()
    
    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
        return label
    }()
    
    let messageLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        return label
    }()
        
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    private func setupViews(){
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
        visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemMaterialDark)
        addSubview(visualEffectView)
        visualEffectView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor)
                
        addSubview(closeImageView)
        closeImageView.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 4), size: .init(width: 30, height: 30))
        closeImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        //38
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.text = "Name of user replying to"
        titleLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: closeImageView.leadingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 0, right: 4))
    
        addSubview(messageLabel)
        messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        messageLabel.text = "This is a long text that is used to test of the view can hold this in the accurate and the right format let us try it out as much as we can"
        messageLabel.anchor(top: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: closeImageView.leadingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 2, left: 4, bottom: 0, right: 4))
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm noticing that you've added the imageView, titleLabel, and messageLabel as subviews even though you have a UIVisualEffectView spanning the entire UIView. Have you tried adding the imageView, titleLabel, and messageLabel as subviews of the UIVisualEffectView?  Another place to look might be the view hierarchy? You can see if there may be another view obstructing the tap gesture.

Comment: @rohanphadte Yes as for your first point dont think thats the case because views are added on a first come basis on top of each other. Your view hierarchy point might be right because I am adding this view on top of the input accessory view. So technically it moves with the keyboard. This is the current hierarchy View -> CollectionView -> Custom Input AccessoryView -> Finally the Keyboard Supplementary View anchored to the top of custom input accessory view. But yet, I don't understand why it wouldn't work

Comment: @rohanphadte I found out what the issue is, I guess. So when I am adding this keyboard supplementary view, I am adding it as a subview of my custom input accessory view & anchoring it to the top. So obviously, even though the supp view is displayed, it's touch area is out of bounds. So I need to add it as a subview to the main view itself. But, how can I get it to attach to the input accessory view cuz xcode throws an error saying "because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."